# How do I create multiple variables using ifelse based on matching names of other variables?

Tags: r

I really struggled to articulate my question so it may actually be a different problem to what the title suggests!
I have a dataframe with 6 factor variables. The variable names are:

```
var_1_1
var_1_2
var_2_1
var_2_2
var_3_1
var_3_2
```

For all the variables ending in a 1 the levels are 'Yes', 'No' and 'Don't know'. All the variables ending in two have two levels - 'Yes' and 'No'.

Where the first 5 characters of the variable names match I want to create a new variable that totals the 'Yes' and 'No' levels of the two semi-matching variables. So I will end up with 9 variables in total, like this:

```
var_1_1
var_1_2
var_1_3
var_2_1
var_2_2
var_2_3
var_3_1
var_3_2
var_3_3
```

My first thought was to do 3 ifelse statements to produce the new variables, but I'm trying to reduce repetition in my code. I imagine it can be done with a for loop or apply but I've got myself very confused trying to do this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

This is how I was originally going to do it, but thought there is probably a way of doing it that is less repetitive...

```
df$var_1_3 <- ifelse(df$var_1_1=="Yes" | df$var_1_2=="Yes","Yes","No") 

df$var_1_3 <- as.factor(df$var_1_3)
```

Comment: Pease give a [mre] in your question!

Comment: *"... in your question!"* https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56442353/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to split the dataset into a list based on the substring on the column names

```
grp <- sub("_\\d+$", "", names(df1))
#or
#grp <- substr(names(df1), 1, 5)
lst1 <- split.default(df1, grp)
```

Loop through the `list` and create the "Yes/No"

```
nm1 <- paste0(names(lst1), "_3")
df1[nm1] <- lapply(lst1, function(x) c("No", "Yes")[(rowSums(x == "Yes") > 0) + 1])
```